# Share same websocket connection in multiple fragments

Tags: android, websocket, singleton, sharedpreferences, getter-setter

I have a websocket connecton, ofcourse it connected well. I am doing the connection in a fragment A, and i am recieving data from server and can print it in a textview.
Now i will open another fragment B. 
Now i want, after opening fragment B, it should recieve data from server using that previously created websocket connection. 
So for this, after googling and searching on SO, i found that i have to store my websocket connection in a singleton variable which i can access in fragment B. How can i do that ? I am new to websocket and singleton, so any help will be appreciated.

Fragment A

```
private void start(String URL) {
 Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();       
            CustomWebSocketListener listener = new CustomWebSocketListener("12345");
            WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
        }
    }

private final class CustomWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
        String KEY;

        public CustomWebSocketListener(String key) {
            this.KEY = key;
        }
        @Override
        public void onOpen(final WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            somePrintFunction("Trying to make connection With Your Server");
            webSocket.send(String.valueOf(KEY));
        }
        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String datastr) {
           somePrintFunction(datastr);
        }
        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
            somePrintFunction(bytes.hex());
        }
        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            somePrintFunction("Closing Connection With Server");
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            somePrintFunction("Connection Error " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Singleton class**

```
public class SocketSingleton {
    private static final SocketSingleton ourInstance = new SocketSingleton();

    public static SocketSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private SocketSingleton() {
    }
}
```

**Fragment B**

```
public class BFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this article is old but still relevant, you should avoid singletons in android
Visit https://medium.com/@programmerr47/singletons-in-android-63ddf972a7e7

for your case, if you are using websockets,then you must be doing for some sort communication(could be chat,data tranfers).
 so in my opinion why dont you store your websocket logic in the main activity containing/handling fragments, and use the values in the activity from fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Change Singleton class like this and try.

```
public class SocketSingleton {
    private static SocketSingleton ourInstance = null;

    public static SocketSingleton getInstance() {
        if (ourInstance == null) {
            ourInstance = new SocketSingleton();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private SocketSingleton() {
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.. but i also want to know, how to store websocket object in singleton and access singleton data from another fragment or activity ?

Comment: Add this one into SocketSingleton class   `static WebSocket ws;
    private void getWebSocket(String url, CustomWebSocketListener listener) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        if (ws == null || !ws.isConnected()) {
            ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
        }
        return ws;`
    }